# Flot plot in bootstrap panel grows infinitely in height when panel opened

Tags: flot

I am trying to show flot plot in a bootstrap panel, utilizing the full height available, starting with the panel closed. When I open the panel the graph keeps growing in height.

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="panel panel-default" >
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title ">
            <a  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#panel1" >
                      <h3>Flot Example - fill height when opened</h3>
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="panel1">
      <div class="panel-body">

         <div id="placeholder"></div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

This jsfiddle demonstrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/65w5xor5/13/